# Choice of model/strategy for multiple regression analysis

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, panel-data, random-effects-model, cross-section

I am doing an econometrics course where I am to do a regression analysis on some firm data.

I want to analyze some shipping data of frozen goods to predict the temperature of the shipped goods at their end destination.

My problem is that I am unsure about which kind of analysis to make when I am interested in both time-variant and in-variant variables.

My data:
I have approx 100 data points for different shipments. For each data point, I have the starting temperature of the products (same for all) and the end temperature after arriving at their end destination. That is my dependent variable. Additionally, I have data for 4 other independent variables:
kg of dry ice (In-variant)
kg of products shipped (In-variant)
time of shipment in days (time-variant)
Ambient temperature during shipment (In-variant)

My model is then:
The temperature of the shipped products = kg of Dry Ice + kg of Products + transport Time + Ambient temperature

Because of my Time variable, I believe that I should do a Panel Data analysis. But as I also want to estimate the effect of some in-variant variables, I should use a Random effect approach.

Or could I simply just frame the model as Cross-sectional not taking into account the time periods (as all shipments have the same starting temperature)

Comment: (1) You are right to add a random effect. The choice is what kind: A random intercept implies the starting temperature affects the final temperature... not unreasonable. A random slope, for example for the ambient temperature, means that different products have a different effect of ambient temperature... also not unreasonable, as they may have different amounts of insulation. Adding both seems attractive, but the more random slopes, the more degrees of freedom you need to estimate them. (2) You may want to consider if any of these variables interact. (ctd.)

Comment: (ctd.) For example, the weight of the product may have a different effect depending on the amount of dry ice. Also welcome to the site :)

Comment: if the time of shipment in days is just an elapsed time, can't the system be reduced to  the equivalent of a time-invariant analysis?

Comment: pedrofigueira: thats what i was thinking about - it that case it would just be a cross-sectional analysis, correct?

Comment: Frans Rodenburg: I figured that random effects are used to control for different factors and remove their variance. But I am interested in all of my variables, and I do not want to remove the. Hence I should use fixed effects. But fixed effects cannot be used for time in-variant variables, so how do I go about that problem?